# Justify stack labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having problems with my stack labels. I have them rotated -90 degrees and I have set align to left and vertical align to bottom. But for some reason the label is aligned to the bottom of each column but not as I expected it to do. The center of the text label is align to the bottom, not the first letter of the label. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without manually calculating the y offset for each individual stack label? And if not, how would I best do that tiresome calculation?

See attached fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'column' },
        title: { text: '' },
        xAxis: { categories: [""] },
        yAxis: [{ 
            title: { text: '', style: { color: '#4572A7'} },
            labels: { 
              formatter: function () { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0) + " USD" }, 
              style: { color: '#4572A7' } 
            },
            stackLabels: { 
            enabled: true, 
            style: { fontSize: '1.5em', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }, 
            formatter: function () { return this.stack; }, 
            rotation: -90, x: -5, 
            verticalAlign: 'bottom', 
            align: 'left' 
        }}],
        legend: { borderWidth: 1, shadow: false },
        plotOptions: { 
           column: { stacking: 'normal' },
           series: { shadow: false} 
        },
        series: [{ data: [34, 34, 54, 12, 23], stack: 'Stack 1' }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zprjn/6/

Cheers!

**EDIT**

This is a simplified version of what I actually have. In my real chart I have dynamic content so there are different texts in the stack labels and the columns have various heights. None of this I know beforehand and thus I need to, somehow, dynamically adjust the stack labels to the bottom (and to the left of) of the columns regardless of the length of the text in the actual label.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! I had to specify

```
textAlign: 'left'
```

as well and that fixed it!

See the updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zprjn/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
verticalAlign: 'middle'
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zprjn/7/

or if you want at bottom, add:

```
y: -40
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zprjn/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yes, you are correct in this perticular and simplified case. But my problem is that I have dynamic content in the graph and thus the stack labels are all with different texts and I don't know in advance what the texts are so I cannot adjust them with  fixed y coordinate like 40. And as for "verticalAlign: 'middle' that won't work either. Firstly because I do want the text to be placed starting at the bottom of the column and going up, but also because that alignment will make the texts being placed at different heights, and even outside the graph with small columns.